# WKWebView is not loading webpage on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I am loading one web URL in WKWebView. I added network transportation layer and all other suggestion provided in different thread. 
But Working perfectly fine on Device bot not working on simulator.
Please let me know what I am missing ?

```
 let preferences = WKPreferences()
    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.preferences = preferences
    webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: webConfiguration)


    webView.uiDelegate = self

    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view.addSubview(webView)

    let request = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(request)
```

Comment: Can you please send your url?

Comment: @shraddha11, I can't share my organisation URL. but can you suggest me what could be possible reason for not loading on simulator ?

Comment: @shraddha11,  https://contents.tdscpc.gov.in/

Comment: try adding https:// while creating url see if that helps. let request = URLRequest(url: "https://contents.tdscpc.gov.in/")...from the code it is not clear whether you have added that or not.

Comment: @pankajnigam See my answer and let me know it works for you or not?

Comment: NSAllowsArbitraryLoads is true at my end but still facing same issue as Pankaj nigam

Answer (score 0):

1.Replace your url to `URL(string: "https://contents.tdscpc.gov.in/")`

After performing step 1 you will got another error related to SSL secure connection. To resolve it you should add below code in your plist.

2. Add this in your plist.

   ```
   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
       <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
       <true/>
   </dict>
   ```

I tried it on simulator and it's worked. 
[image: See result here]